# limit the value of a slider dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want a slider with range 0 to 2400, which is limited by another slider's value. Together they only may add up to 2400. I have tried to implement it in the change method like this:

```
var cal_sl = $("#sl_4");
cal_sl.attr('max', 2400);   
cal_sl.change(function()
{
    var sumv = ($("#sl_3").val()*1)+($(this).val()*1);
    if(sumv>2400)
    {
        $(this).val(2400-$("#sl_3").val());            
    }
    var slider_value = $(this).val();

});
```

But then the slider won't move (only the text box of the slider would be correct). If I also add a refresh, the change function would enter an infinite loop of refreshing/changing/refreshing/...

Also, I do not want to change the 'max' value, since the thumb should be in the middle of the slider with a value 1200, but it should not be able to move to a higher value if the other slider has a value of 1200 as well.

How could this be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to set the refresh within the if, this way the infinite loop does not happen:

```
$(this).slider('refresh');
```